# Check if a filename has multiple '.'/periods in it

Tags: python, file, bottle

So I'm making a website and in one of the pages you can upload images.

I didn't think of this before when making my file upload function but files are allowed to have multiple `.` in them, so how can I differentiate between the "real" `.` and the fake `.` to get the filename and the extension.

This is my file upload function, which isn't especially relevant but it shows how I upload the files:

```
def upload_files(files, extensions, path, overwrite=False, rename=None):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    filepath = None
    for file in files:
        name, ext = file.filename.split('.')
        if ext in extensions or extensions == '*':
            if rename:
                filepath = path + rename + '.' + ext if path else rename + '.' + ext
            else:
                filepath = path + file.filename if path else file.filename

            file.save(filepath, overwrite=overwrite)
        else:
            raise Exception('[ FILE ISSUE ] - File Extension is not allowed.')
```

As you can see I am splitting the filename based on the `.` that is there but I now need to split it and figure out which `.` split pair is the actual pair for filename and extension, it also creates the issue of providing too many values for the declaration `name, ext` since there is a third var now at least.

Comment: Extension would always go at the end of the filename. Moreover, you shouldn't be allowing any extension of file to be uploaded. Perform some integrity check of some sort with the bare minimum being the name of the file ending in .jpg or .tar.gz or .tgz, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `os.path.splitext` which will split your filename into a name and extension part

```
import os

print(os.path.splitext("./.././this.file.ext"))
# => ('./.././this.file', '.ext')
```

Comment: This won't work. What if someone is trying to upload a tar file? The extension in that case would be .tar.gz but splitext would give you filename.tar, .gz.

Comment: Then you do the heavy work with `os.path.splittext` and regular `split` the last item.

Comment: Well, a .tar.gz is a tarball compressed into a gzip, so I would say the proper extension is gz. If you want to check for multiple levels of extentsions, use a loop/recursive function to gather all extensions.

Comment: This works thankyou, I noticed whiplash's comment about `.tar.gz` but this is fine for my question since I'm only allowing images for this upload

Answer (score -2):

So after going through your query I thought of something which might help you.

**Method-1:**
If you have some pre defined extensions like jpg, png, jpeg, pdf, docx, ppt, csv, xlxd ..... you can make a list of these and use that to separate your file extension

```
filename = Anindya.Patro.pdf
    
for I in filename.split('.'):
    if I in list_of_files:
      Do your operation
```

This is a brute force kinda idea.

**Method-2:**
The extensions are always at the last of file name - like you don't find files like Anindya.pdf.Patro

So you can access it in two ways:

1. By splitting at last . only
2. split the filename and do filename[-1] which will give you the last word after split

```
l = filename.split('.')
extension = l[-1]
```